# RStudio Error with Tidy - Column 6 must be named

Tags: r, broom

I'm trying to use `tidy` to put a regression result into table format to export to Excel. My codes worked fine last month, but today I got `Error: Column 6 must be named`. Below is an example:

```
CarReg = lm(formula = speed ~., data = cars)
# Standardize coefficients
library(lm.beta)
CarRegS = lm.beta::lm.beta(CarReg)
# Table format
library(broom)
tidy(CarRegS)
Error: Column 6 must be named
```

Comment: I would submit that as a bug report on the github page. https://github.com/tidymodels/broom/issues

Comment: Thanks @Phil. I just did. Is there a workaround?

Comment: You could go back a version by downloading whatever version you used before here: https://cran.r-project.org/src/contrib/Archive/broom/ and try again. Otherwise, what were you looking to extract? If you have an example of what the final data should look like, it would help create a custom solution.

Comment: @Phil version 0.4.1 worked! Thanks a lot!

Comment: np - you may want to point that out in the issue you filed on their github page.

Comment: @Phil Yep, I just did.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue after I started a new R session (but with tidy on a lmer function instead of your lm.beta). Probably because of delayed loading of broom tools. After it loaded (after +- 5 minutes) it worked as when I wrote the script.
Hope that helps!